# Directive "&" expression not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have made two directives that embed a swf object onto the page for playing and recording videos. There is a global function each swf uses to signal player events. The code for the player looks like

js:

```
scope: {
    onVideoPlay:  "&"
},
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

    window.PlayerFuncs = {
        onPlay: function() {
            scope.onVideoPlay();
        }
    }

}
```

html:

```
<my-video-directive on-video-play="parentFunc()"></my-video-directive>
```

The recorder code is nearly identical with the only difference being the window.PlayerFuncs is just called window.RecorderFuncs, the event funcs are onVideoRecord, etc.

As you can see, the flash player calls PlayerFuncs.onPlay() when it is playing, and the directive passes this info on to the parent controller via the isolate scope onVideoPlay expression. This system works perfectly with the recorder, but not in the player. I have pulled the scope.onVideoPlay() line out of the PlayerFuncs object to test my syntax, and it works perfectly OUTSIDE that object, but as soon as I put it in there it seems not to bind to the parentFunc() expression. Console logging scope.onVideoPlay shows that it is still an angular wrapper for something, but apparently that something is not parentFunc(). Keep in mind this EXACT method works flawlessly in the recorder directive. What could be going on here?

I even tried this:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

    scope.doStuff = function() {
        scope.onVideoPlay();
    };

    scope.doStuff();

    window.PlayerFuncs = {
        onPlay: function() {
            scope.doStuff();
        }
    }

}
```

The call to `doStuff()` inside the `window.PlayerFuncs` doesn't work, but the call outside does!

Comment: is `window.PlayerFuncs.onPlay()` invoked or not?

Comment: Yes. A console.log inside onPlay and also one inside doStuff reveals the window.PlayerFuncs is indeed calling onPlay and doStuff.

Comment: do you have something inside `scope.onVideoPlay()` that updates the scope?

Comment: @ryeballar has it right.  Whenever you get an event from outside the angular ecosystem (in this case, from flash), you almost always have to call `scope.$apply()` to tell angular that something has changed.

Comment: I am also passing a video object into the directive that contains the urls for the flv and its thumbnail this way: `scope: { video: "=" }`. When `parentFunc()` is called, it does update the parent object to this video object by incrementing another property `views`. Would this really affect it?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `scope.$apply()`.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

    window.PlayerFuncs = {
        onPlay: function() {
            scope.onVideoPlay();
            scope.$apply();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: scope.$apply doesn't do it, and the recorder doesn't seem to need this anyway to work just fine.

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in a plunker? or a jsfiddle? it'll help up trace the problem better.

Comment: atm i'm getting around this issue by using $rootScope.$broadcast inside `PlayerFuncs.onPlay`, and thats working perfectly, no scope.$apply or any other modifications.

Comment: I have made a jsfiddle but I don't know how to simulate a flash object calling methods on a global object like window.PlayerFuncs. I can't fully recreate the conditions in my real code.

Comment: I would really love to get to the bottom of this though. i don't like that i am having to use $broadcast as a work around in one directive and not in another nearly identical directive.

Comment: If you can create a plunker I'd be able to help you find the problem better.